# Typescript: Typing a combinator for reducer-like functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, higher-order-functions, reducers, combinators

Consider the following types

```
type Reducer<S, A> = Red<S, A, A>
type Red<S, C, A> = (s: S) => (c: C) => A
```

and the following function

```
// The type intended for `reds` is
//     `{ [k in keyof P]: Red<S, P, P[k]> }`
// for fixed `S` and `P`

const combinator: ??? = reds =>
  step => acc =>
    {
      const result = {}

      for (const key in reds) {
        result[key] = reds[key](step)(acc)
      }

      return result
    }
```

Now consider the following application (in ts) of this function:

```
const reducer = combinator({
  first: (s: "S") => ({ first, second }) => {
    // *1
    return "whatever"
  },
  second: (s: "S") => ({ first, second }) => {
    // *1
    return 5
  },
})
```

**Question:** How can we define **a type for the function `combinator`**  in typescript such that

1. The const `reducer` has type `Reducer<"S", { first: "whatever", second: 5 }>`
2. In the scope of the lines marked with `// *1` the types of `first` and `second` are correctly inferred as `first: "whatever"` and `second: 5`

In short: What should we put in the following code in place of `???`

```
const combinator: ??? = reds => { ... }
```

*[Remark]: I posted a partial solution. Maybe it helps as a starting point?*

---

edit:

The motivation for the combinator is to allow for parallel reducing with mutually referencing reducers. The use case I have in mind is compiling an AST. But to keep it simpler: [Here's a contrived example](https://repl.it/@GerritBegher/ReducerCombinator-1#index.js):

```
const combinator = reds =>
  step => acc =>
    {
      const result = {}

      for (const key in reds) {
        result[key] = reds[key](step)(acc)
      }

      return result
    }

const reduce = arr => ({ init, red }) =>
  {
    let acc = init

    for (const step of arr) {
      acc = red(step)(acc)
    }

    return acc
  }

const exampleInput = [
  "some line",
  "some other line",
  "yet another line",
]

const exampleReducer = combinator({
  textWithLengths:
    line => ({ textWithLengths, totalLength }) =>
      textWithLengths + "\n" + `${totalLength} -- ${line}`,
  totalLength:
    line => ({ totalLength }) =>
      totalLength + line.length,
  startsWithSame:
    line => ({ startsWithSame, previousLine }) =>
      [...startsWithSame, previousLine.charAt(0) === line.charAt(0)],
  previousLine:
    line => _ =>
      line
})

const exampleInit = {
  textWithLengths: "",
  totalLength: 0,
  startsWithSame: [],
  previousLine: "",
}

const exampleResult = reduce(exampleInput)({
  init: exampleInit,
  red: exampleReducer
})

console.log(exampleResult.textWithLengths)
console.log(exampleResult.startsWithSame)
```

The output will be

```
// console.log(exampleResult.textWithLengths)

0 -- some line
9 -- some other line
24 -- yet another line
[ false, true, false ]
```

```
// console.log(exampleResult.startsWithSame)
[ false, true, false ]
```

Comment: In your use case, can you predict the values ```whatever``` and ```5```? If so, I have something here that can help you out

Comment: This is the third time I read this question. I really would like to answer, but it seems that I can't find a use case, so I can't really understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks A.Chiesa . I updated the question with an example.

Comment: I posted a partial answer. Maybe someone could improve on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the definition of types is a little bit convoluted.
I don't know if you have "collateral" requirements, given the other code, but, evaluated in a vacuum, something like this could work (untested, except for type coercion):

```
const exampleInput = [
    "some line",
    "some other line",
    "yet another line",
]

interface Aggr {
    textWithLengths: string;
    totalLength: number;
    startsWithSame: boolean[];
    previousLine: string;
}

const exampleInit: Aggr = {
    textWithLengths: "",
    totalLength: 0,
    startsWithSame: [],
    previousLine: "",
}

type Reducers<TInput, TOutput> = {
    [k in keyof TOutput]: (input: TInput, aggr: TOutput) => TOutput[k];
};

const reduce = function <TInput, TOutput>(
    input: TInput[],
    init: TOutput,
    reducers: Reducers<TInput, TOutput>
) {
    let acc = init;
    const reducerNames = Object.keys(reducers);
    for (const item of input) {
        const newAcc: any = {};

        for (const reducerName of reducerNames) {
            const red = (reducers as any)[reducerName];
            newAcc[reducerName] = red(item, acc);
        }

        acc = newAcc as TOutput;
    }

    return acc;
};

// types can be implicitly checked
const result = reduce<string, Aggr>(exampleInput, exampleInit, {
    textWithLengths: (line, aggr) =>
        aggr.textWithLengths + "\n" + `${aggr.totalLength} -- ${line}`,
    totalLength: (line, aggr) => aggr.totalLength + line.length,
    startsWithSame: (line, aggr) => [
        ...aggr.startsWithSame,
        aggr.previousLine.charAt(0) === line.charAt(0),
    ],
    previousLine: (line) => line,
});

console.log(result.textWithLengths)
console.log(result.startsWithSame)
```

Instead of `TInput[]`, you could use another interface, like `Iterator<TInput>`.

Edit: I updated the code fixing some type mismatches inside reduce and tested it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOBJMaCusAvDANoBQMVMARBCCnDBgJZhw0A0l1dDTIKAAs4AJ2ZsO3arQCecWEjCCR41uy7kAuuXJsoYgGZJgTAIIBzC%20IDePKgYRQA6i2EAZOGAvCIALhhoUTYLAG57GChBJAxPb2EAsHwUACMxcJloJFEoCFdhAGVUOACUkBAsJVItDOo0UTgANxYQfAh3SQCgkPCAX11QSFhEVEwcMDcAy2sYEjsZRxc3ITifIX9aTQXo2K81gIAGaWosnLzlosYA6uOqeqaWto72AJpNfvIoWTQmACU4AAm%20FMoggAB4ACq4AhQTgwCEAeUIMIAfLMYPNqKQANYwNgwbFwWQgQzwpFQGFaAIACjYMICULwhDhSCsogZ5JhAEpZmjEcjCDiauReuFyINoDAGkDTOjDPgwMAoC0wDBIdDmWSBVAUdSInTCAyNVAbvqJlAOdrblLAcCxBt-jL7eqmbCtRTCCjyDzMVQsIpgMB0Ww3LUqBLYNK7aIAHLFCDohEpABWcCVADpCbIINSoyCIFywzBDCBxNSI3iDCgYCS8a6fREZBX2AB3MyBgJKWTomyi3QyGQlssVvNiOOMGuk0ex%20MNgfzmAjwHo3O2-MwJAJrtc0jT8dwYULget9vAXdrsfFLTo6W0qsswOFxvUD5HkxBkgnwMbhP8j1QItX2oBooHwURVXfPoxQAemgyJvjgBNgCUGA0jxdBWGANwMG7YARGAQkAXFcBJQaCB8AwYgbSdMFum8OFplEXURgw8YYThFixlwNw4V9SJECWDw9l8Gl1DgFk2R5IgvTfNl00WfIVmE9YYAAaloAAdMAaDUmAAAMABIbFZax5J2VZhF6GAAFprJgIyxN6PTrSiKAYgsoRRMkCTrCktETNEMy3N2eIhF0sT0ywULrVOXJFMuEoYGpMSfNEPyyGfKh02ygL01i85CmKa0ZFy%205mladpJHTPDsjMKBqQOKSiBICKatEOqGq5a0tGtMrHkql4krE9KUpFJ9iMgCo4EikALFXcjKPkgTFI8gsJvoLAZrmsiKKgPK3LOeLii5cggA). Seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes. This is similar to what I've come up with when solving the problem. The downside however is that it is not a typing for the reducer itself: We'll be bound to always carry around a given input. Another advantage of using an actual combinator is that we can apply transducers like map to the reducer rather than reducing over the input twice.

Comment: I admit I am a bit lost in "Another advantage of using an actual combinator is that we can apply transducers like map to the reducer rather than reducing over the input twice". About not having a typing for the reducer itself: what's wrong with the `type Reducers<TInput, TOutput>` above? It seems to me it's exactly the typing you're not getting. What am I missing?

Comment: In fact, inside the call to reduce in the example, you have type checking about the input type, the aggregated value, and the type of the value returned.

Comment: I'm explicitly looking for a typing of the function I called `combinator`. This function has roughly the signature `combinator: reducers -> reducer`. In your answer you presented two typings: One is a function with signature `reduce: (input, init, reducers) -> output` and the other typing, what you named `Reducer`, defines a `Record` of reducers.). While related, these are different things.

Comment: Regarding the advantage I mentioned of decoupling reducers from the reduce function:  Here's a great article explaining this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/efficient-data-transformations-using-transducers-c779043ba655/

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a partial solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShAmAeAygGigYXQQQHxQF4oAKAZwC4pkBKQ-YgY0o1oP2wChRJYEBXBhABOKHPiJwkaKNjEd53aABUAhkIDmEYIhhQIAD2AQAdvFK8kK4yHRWbUO7nFQOUN7D2GTZi4ju3rdABLYwAzYSpcV3cYgH4qaJi3SgBtACJgAAsg81JMgHs%20ABt4KGN84ChMlTBIY0oGQpKyiqgQ8KEoYDVNSsUofNCoIX5BITT0GABdeS5waAx8gFsAIxCEVQ0tHQRzAyNTcwBvKBSAa0pSYCEQ9SnKST9Ah2fHKABfcUSoE-O24ygZwgIEGFlI9ygm16OzM5ym%20Hes0axiuwwgDE6RFEYM8Bx8vwuUCuN2MdweCGx-heIARuGI3xGZnJZm%201GZAmE2MWq3W8Ch20kpCcdG%20MTIlBodBIYGYyzWxg2PQFu1wrCiSQ1P1FmpiyNRI1IxWAlAACmpgEEVEVENz5YqttpBcKiEdEdqdW5QvlOox8ijKkCQP80WZaEd3R6YgajedgVNCCHSLGQFMyNRiGBqBGdW7IxqRsA%20EIAdGipUVOZbbz%20Y6Vdn3G6OHrKqXKkQRhjiOGYqEgkIrpRxVA0sg0mqSCde-3gOhSOi-aV3uPu5qAPSrqAAKgAjBGC0WAduHOZdzF3qhvnPkfBBxRh6Px12oFOrrP56YPsuI%20utwAmPdaAeUC-sewHfOeHBLhwQA). But it's not the full answer: The problem is that at the marked places in the code (at `*1`, `*2`), the types of `first` and `second` are not inferred correctly. We only get `first: any` and `second: any` while it should be `first: 1` and `second: 2`.

```
type Red<S, C, A> = (s: S) => (c: C) => A
type Reducer<S, A> = Red<S, A, A>


type Target<R extends Red<any, any, any>> = 
    R extends Red<any, any, infer S>
        ? S
        : ["this should not happen: could not infer target type of reducer", R]


type CombinedTarget<Reds extends { [k: string]: Red<any, any, any> }> =
    { [k in keyof Reds]: Target<Reds[k]> }


const combinator = <S, Reds extends { [k: string]: Red<S, any, any> }>(
    reds: Reds
    ): Reducer<S, CombinedTarget<Reds>> =>
        (s: S) => (p: CombinedTarget<Reds>) =>
            {
                const result: Partial<CombinedTarget<Reds>> = {}

                for (const key in reds) {
                    result[key] = reds[key](s)(p)
                }

                return result as CombinedTarget<Reds>
            }


const result = combinator({
    first: (s: "S") => ({ first, second }) => {
        // *1
        return 1 as 1
    },
    second: (s: "S") => ({ first, second }) => {
        // *2
        return 2 as 2
    },
})
```